# A built-in way to manipulate the order of the items in the legend

Tags: plotting, functions, legending

I have several lists that I plot on the same image like this:

```
lst02 = {{0.6, 0.0844}, {0.7, 0.077}, {0.8, 0.069}, {0.9, 0.058}};
lst022 = {{0.2, 0.779}, {0.25, 0.597}, {0.3, 0.542}, {0.4, 0.419}};
lst023 = {{0.3, 0.76}, {0.4, 0.555}, {0.5, 0.47}, {0.6, 0.369}};

ListPlot[{lst02, lst022, lst023}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{Style["a=0.20", 12, Italic], 
     Style["a=0.22", 12, Italic], Style["a=0.23", 12, Italic]}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"], Scaled[{0.85, 0.75}]]]
```

which yields the following plot:

[image]

What I now would like to achieve is to force the legend to be shown in the reverse order. That is, a=0.23 - on top, then a=0.22, and a=0.20 at the bottom of the legend. In this case it would go in the same order as the points on the plot: firstdiamonds, then squares then - disks.

I realize that there is the possibility to make a custom legend. That I can and will do, if no better way could be offered.

I just would like to ask you, if you know a simple built-in way to manipulate the order of the items in the legend.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `"ReversedColumn"` as the `LegendLayout` option setting:

```
ListPlot[{lst02, lst022, lst023}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{Style["a=0.20", 12, Italic], 
     Style["a=0.22", 12, Italic], Style["a=0.23", 12, Italic]}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"], 
   Scaled[{0.85, 0.75}]]]
```

[image]

You can also use `LegendLayout -> (Grid[Reverse @ #] &)` to get the same result.